Swift で Hashable(Equatable) に準拠したジェネリクス型の値を比較できない
学習のためジェネリクスを用いて汎用的なベクトルを作ろうとして次のようなコードを作成しましたが，「Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'any Hashable' operands」というエラーが出てしまいました．HashableはEquatableに準拠しているので比較できるだろうと考えておりました．
このコードの問題点とどのようにすれば==演算子を実装できるかご教示いただけますと幸いです．
Swift version 5.8.1
protocol Vector:Hashable{
    associatedtype T:Hashable
    associatedtype U:Hashable
    static func == (lhs: any Vector, rhs: any Vector) -> Bool
    var x:T { get set }
    var y:U { get set }
}

extension Vector{
    init(x:T,y:U){
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
    static func == (lhs: any Vector, rhs: any Vector) -> Bool {
        if lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y{ return true }
        return false
    }
}

struct Int2DimVector:Vector{
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}



extensionの中にコンストラクターは記述しない
== の引数は any Vectorではなくselfを使う

という点が問題です。
associatedtypeが使われている場合、anyで、そのプロトコル準拠型を抽象化すると型の情報が失われます。そのため、== (lhs: any Vector, rhs: any Vector)では型が解決されませんので型が正しく推論出来る様にしてあげる必要があります。
よって、回答としてコードを書き替えると
protocol Vector: Hashable {
    associatedtype T: Hashable
    associatedtype U: Hashable

    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool

    var x: T { get set }
    var y: U { get set }
}

extension Vector {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
    }
}

struct Int2DimVector: Vector {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int

    init(x: Int, y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

というコードになるかと思います。　また、適宜スペースを入れる事でコードの可読性が上がると思います

問題点の指摘ありがとうございます．
型の抽象化についてもう少し理解を深めようと思います．
2点目のご指摘について理解できたのですが，extensionでコンストラクタを記述する問題点はどのようなものになりますでしょうか．

プロトコルはあるクラス・構造体が取りうる振る舞いを定義する場所で、インスタンスを生成する機能はありません。なので、インスタンスを生成するためのメソッドであるコンストラクターを定義するのは不適切で、そのプロトコルの具象化である、実クラス・構造体にコンストラクターの記述を任せるべきだからです
